# Как лаконично оформить код?

Tags: php

Есть вот такая небольшая функция. Есть ли способ сделать её более ёмкой и производительной? Может другой конструкцией (не if else) или по-другому сравнение реализовать?
P.S. изучать PHP только начинаю

```
function game_parameters_check($gameMode, $level, $betValue)
{
    if($gameMode != 'real' && $gameMode != 'demo')
    {
        exit();
    }
    if($level != 'easy' && $level != 'medium' &&  $level != 'hard')
    {
        exit();
    }
    if($betValue < 15 || $betValue > 500)
    {
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну, для начала, название функций принято писать в `lowerCamelCase`, прям как ваши переменные. А так-то по коду особо оптимизировать нечего,  разве всё в одно условие кинуть - смысл дублировать `exit();`?

Comment: Ну и можно как-то так сделать `$levels = ['easy','medium','hard']; if ( !in_array($level,$levels) ) {...}` опять же, на производительность у вашем примере очень трудно повлиять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> P.S. изучать PHP только начинаю

Мой ответ не будем о том, как записать код в три строчки.

**1 Название функции**

Обычно глагол ставят в начало названия: get, set, update, check, validate и т.д. Название функции/метода должно отражать, что она/он делают. Таким образом `check_game_parameters`: проверка параметров игры.

**2 Назначение функции**

Такое обилие `exit` в одной функции и без вывода сообщений об ошибках - это не серьезно. Еще пару-тройку таких функций и потом замучаетесь бегать по всему приложению с `var_dump`.

Если это функция проверки/валидации, то она как минимум должна возвращать `true` или `false`. Таким образом: если переданные параметры игры удовлетворяют некоторым заранее определенным условиям, то возвращаем `true`. Во всех остальных случаях - `false`.

**3 Аргументы функции**

На входе имеем три аргумента, каждый из которых проходит по две-три проверки. Итого на текущий момент - [7 проверок](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0).

> Почти всегда проблемы возникают из-за слишком длинных методов, часто содержащих
>   массу информации, погребенной под сложной логикой, которую они обычно в себе заключают. Основным типом рефакторинга здесь служит «Выделение метода», в результате которого фрагмент кода превращается в отдельный метод. -- *Мартин Фаулер*.

В нашем случае не метод, а функция. Три аргумента - три отдельных функции, от которых нам нужно либо `true`, либо `false`.

**4 Именование аргументов**

1. `$gameMode` - проверяем параметры игры, поэтому приставка `game` излишня.
2. `$level` отлично.
3. `$betValue` - из контекста и так понятно, что это значение.

---

```
echo '<pre>';

function check_game_parameters($mode, $level, int $bet)
{
    return validate_mode($mode)
        && validate_level($level)
        && validate_bet($bet);
}

function validate_mode($mode) {
    return in_array($mode, [
            'real',
            'demo'
        ]);
}

function validate_level($level) {
    return in_array($level, [
            'easy',
            'medium',
            'hard'
        ]);
}

function validate_bet(int $bet) {
    return $bet >= 15 && $bet <= 500;
}

if (!check_game_parameters('real', 'hard', 15)) {
    echo 'Проверка не пройдена<br>';
    exit();
}

echo 'Проверка пройдена<br>';
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый полный ответ! В процессе написания я решил вывести в exit() сообщения той или иной ошибки, но ваш вариант я учту на будущее для похожих ситуаций. Еще думаю можно скомбинировать ваш подход и вывод разных сообщений, сравнивая в обобщающей функции check_game_parameters() полученные строки вспомогательных функций (в общих чертах описал).

Answer (score 1):

Ну, в голову приходит только два варианта:

```
function game_parameters_check($gameMode, $level, $betValue) {
    if($gameMode != 'real' && $gameMode != 'demo') exit();
    if($level != 'easy' && $level != 'medium' &&  $level != 'hard') exit();
    if($betValue < 15 || $betValue > 500) exit();
}
```

Либо же

```
function game_parameters_check($gameMode, $level, $betValue) {
    if(!in_array($gameMode, [ 'real', 'demo' ])) exit();
    if(!in_array($level, [ 'easy', 'medium', 'hard' ])) exit();
    if($betValue < 15 || $betValue > 500) exit();
}
```

Во втором варианте, лучше, конечно же, переменную gameMode перевести в нижний регистр.

Answer (score 1):

```
function check_game_parameters($gameMode, $level, $betValue)
{
    $allowedRule = [
        'level' => ['easy','medium','hard'],
        'game_mode' => ['real','demo'],

    ];

    if(! in_array($gameMode,$allowedRule['game_mode']) ||
        ! in_array($level,$allowedRule['level'])) exit();


    if($betValue <= 15 || $betValue > 400) exit();

}
```

А если в будущем добавится еще один уровень, или игровой режим? добавлять новые if'ы? 
В данном случае достаточно этот новый режим\уровень добавить в массив `$allowedRule`